# MVC 4 Regular Expression in View Model - Pagers or Mobile Numbers

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get users to enter multiple 5 digit pager or 10 digit phone numbers separated by comma, space or semicolon using the regular expression below:

```
[RegularExpression("([0-9]{5|10}([ ,;]+)?)+", ErrorMessage = @"Please enter either 5 digit or 10 digit numbers separated by a space, comma or semicolon")]
[DisplayName(@"Pager/Mobile Numbers (e.g 0402123499; 0302039855, 12345 67890; 20123) ")]
public string MobileOrSmsNumbers { get; set; }
```

That does not work. Also, a user should not use two spaces or comma and semi-colon or space and comma, etc to separate the digits. There should be only one separating character.The last number does not need anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This does the trick. The last entry will not have any semi-colon, comma or space.

```
([0-9]{5}([;, ])|[0-9]{10}([;, ]))*([0-9]{5}|[0-9]{10})+
```

Here's what it tests:
12345; 1234567890; 23495, 1290394990, 12312

Comment: That still doesn't look right.  The numbers in your example are separated by semicolon *and space* (`; `) or comma *and space* (`, `), but your regex allows for semicolon **or** comma **or** space.  Which is it?  Also, the `+` at the end of the regex is incorrect.

Comment: Yes I wanted it to be separated by semicolon or comma or space. That's what the question was.Why is + incorrect? It basically means one or more..

Comment: `([0-9]{5}|[0-9]{10})` already matches five or ten digits.  By adding the `+`, you allow the last number to contain fifteen, twenty, three hundred... any number of digits, as long as it's a multiple of five.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

`^(([0-9]{5}|[0-9]{10})([ ,;]?))+$`

`{5|10}` is not valid - see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx

Also - your sample is incorrect. `04021234` is only 8 numbers

Comment: I fixed that example.

Comment: @DiwasPathak It still breaks the constraint `There should be only one separating character` when separating by `'; '` (semi colon plus space) :)